# Printing a PDF automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, pdf

I have a webservice that has a crystal report that generates an invoice from my database and then exports the crystal to a `PDF`, into a stream and then returns as a string on the web method.

On the client side I have a Winforms `C#` app that calls this webservice. I would like to be able to automatically print the `PDF` on the client side without opening Acrobat Reader.

I would preferably not want to save the `PDF` either because currently I have to save the `PDF` then use a process to open Acrobat Reader and then print the `PDF`.

Comment: Why can the server not just print the invoice?

Answer (score 5):

There is a free utility called SumatraPDF that lets you print PDF documents silently. I have succesfully used it in a winform app.

```
private void print(string printerName, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "SumatraPDF.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-print-to " + '"' + printerName+ '"' + " " + '"' + fileName+ '"';
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("InboundServicioImpresion", ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

For the "automatic print", you could use a Timer or a infinite loop that executes the method above.

Comment: SumatraPDF is slow if you're doing a lot of printing in a batch and you need speed. From the SumatraPDF forum: "In general Sumatra is not great at printing so I wouldn't recommend using it in this scenario. Currently we print by generating a bitmap for each page and sending those bitmaps to a printer. Adobe is smarter."

Comment: Yup. 6 years ago sounded nice, but experience has shown that it's quite slow and resource hungry on a batch scenario.

Comment: I haven't used it yet but it looks like VeryPDF has a PDF printer software that might be a better choice. Just don't know what it's performance is like.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge. The solution I've made was buying a component called PDFTron. It has an API to send pdf documents to a printer from an unattended service. I posted some information in my blog about that. Take a look!

[How to print a PDF file programmatically???](http://blog.robertolopes.com/2010/11/17/how-to-print-a-pdf-file-programmatically/)

Thanks,

Roberto Lopes

Comment: The url has changed. It's now http://blog.robertolopes.com/2012/08/16/how-to-print-a-pdf-file-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command line:

```
acrord32 /t "out.pdf" "Acrobat Distiller" "AdobePS Acrobat Distiller" "in.pdf"
```

The syntax is:

> acroRd32.exe /t path printername drivername portname
>
> - Initiates Acrobat Reader, prints a file while suppressing the Acrobat print dialog box, then
>     terminates Reader.

Comment: Hi John, This is not a reliable solution. I tried before. Also, if breaks the Acrobat Licensing. I contacted Adobe few years ago on this, and they said that acrobat is a desktop application for "viewing" pdf files. I opted by using PDFTron at that point, and it is still running like a charm.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that feedback, Roberto. I had been using this earlier (three years ago, when this answer was written!) without any issue, but I just tried it again today and it does seem flaky. Thanks!